# Scaling instances along curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

Float curve node marked with red doesn't work as it should. It does so only when i delete group of nodes marked with yellow, but then i don't get random istances destribution in volume. Any ideas how to achieve this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to keep the captured attribute when converting to a volume. You need to get the factor from some kind of geometry.

It is possible to [Sample Nearest Surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/sample/sample_nearest_surface.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-geometrynodesamplenearestsurface) like this:

[image: Use a Sample Nearest Surface-node on the geometry before it is turned into a volume]